# How to pass props to parent (Material-UI React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I've looked everywhere for a solution, with no luck.

I am trying to pass a parent React component's `this.state.nextID` to the child component as a property.  However, when I try to access that property in the child, it is null.  I am using Material-UI for react and I think the problem is with the `withStyles` function, because when I inspect the source of the page, I see the `key` property on the `withStyles(ServerBlock)` node.  But then there is a child of that node that is `ServerBlock`, with no `key` property.  What am I doing wrong?

`ConfigBlock.js`

```
class ConfigBlock extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
    children: [],
    nextID: 0
    }
    this.handleChildUnmount = this.handleChildUnmount.bind(this);
  }
  handleChildUnmount = (key) => {
    console.log(key)
    this.state.children.splice(key, 1);
    this.setState({children: this.state.children});
  }
  addServerBlock() {
    this.state.children.push({"id": this.state.nextID, "obj": <ServerBlock unmountMe={this.handleChildUnmount} key={this.state.nextID} />})
   this.setState({children: this.state.children})
    this.state.nextID += 1
  }
  addUpstreamBlock() {
    this.state.children.push({"id": this.state.nextID, "obj": <UpstreamBlock unmountMe={this.handleChildUnmount} key={this.state.nextID} />})
    this.setState({children: this.state.children})
    this.state.nextID += 1
  }
  render () {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <Card className={classes.card}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography className={classes.title} color="primary">
              Config
            </Typography>
                <div>
              {this.state.children.map((child, index) => {
                return (child.obj);
              })}
            </div>
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} onClick={ this.addServerBlock.bind(this) }>
              Server
              <AddIcon />
            </Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} onClick={ this.addUpstreamBlock.bind(this) }>
              Upstream
              <AddIcon />
            </Button>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ConfigBlock.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ConfigBlock);
```

`ServerBlock.js`

```
class ServerBlock extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      children: []
    }
  }
  addServerBlock() {
    this.state.children.push(<NginxEntry/>)
    this.setState({children: this.state.children})
  }
  deleteMe = () => {
    this.props.unmountMe(this.props.key);
  }
  render () {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <Card className={classes.card}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography className={classes.title} color="primary">
              Server
            </Typography>

          </CardContent>
          <CardActions>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} onClick={() => { console.log('onClick'); }}>
              Key/Value
              <AddIcon />
            </Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} onClick={() => { console.log('onClick'); }}>
              Location
              <AddIcon />
            </Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} onClick={() => { console.log('onClick'); }}>
              Comment
              <AddIcon />
            </Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} onClick={ this.deleteMe }>
              <DeleteIcon />
            </Button>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ServerBlock.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ServerBlock);
```

Comment: without reading your lengthy post, based on your title: You cannot pass prop to parent rather you can call parent function passed in Child component as props.

Answer (score 0):

`key` is a special React attribute, it is not a prop, i.e. the child will never have access to it's value. If the child needs to use that value, provide it via another prop (as well as via the key), e.g.

```
<ServerBlock
  unmountMe={this.handleChildUnmount}
  key={this.state.nextID}
  id={this.state.nextID}
/>
```

---

...Aside from that, your code is quite unusual. You should not be directly mutating state (you should always use `setState`), and you wouldn't normally store whole components in your state. Just as food for thought here's an alternative (untested) implementation of your `ConfigBlock` component that uses `setState` and shifts around some of the logic a bit:

```
class ConfigBlock extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      nextID = 0,
      children: [],
    }
    this.handleChildUnmount = this.handleChildUnmount.bind(this);
    // bind this function once here rather than creating new bound functions every render
    this.addBlock = this.addBlock.bind(this)
  }

  handleChildUnmount = (key) => {
    console.log(key)
    this.setState(state => {
      return {
        // `state.children.splice(key, 1)`, aside from mutating the state,
        // will not work as expected after the first unmount as the ids and
        // array positions won't stay aligned
        children: state.children.slice().filter(child => child.id !== key)
      }
    })
  }

  // Consolidate the two addBlock functions, given we're determining the type
  // of component to render in the render function.
  addBlock(blockType) {
    this.setState(state => {
      return {
        children: [...state.children, { id: state.nextID, type: blockType }]
        nextID: state.nextID + 1
      }
    })
  }

  render () {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <Card className={classes.card}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography className={classes.title} color="primary">
              Config
            </Typography>
            <div>
              {this.state.children.map(child => {
                // determine the component to render here rather than in the handlers
                if (child.type === 'server') {
                  return <ServerBlock key={child.id} id={child.id} unmountMe={this.handleChildUnmount(child.id)} />
                } else if (child.type === 'upstream') {
                  return <UpstreamBlock key={child.id} id={child.id} unmountMe={this.handleChildUnmount(child.id)} />
                }
              })}
            </div>
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} onClick={this.addBlock('server')}>
              Server
              <AddIcon />
            </Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} onClick={this.addBlock('upstream')}>
              Upstream
              <AddIcon />
            </Button>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```